# What Does Backwards Compatible Mean If There Are Breaking Changes

Tags: open-source, semantic-versioning

I've noticed something strange in a few open source projects that use Semantic Version. In React 15, the React team [switched to semver](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/02/19/new-versioning-scheme.html). Similarly, the Angular team switched to semver in Angular 2.0.0.

Semver declares that a major version bump will happen ["when you make incompatible API changes"](http://semver.org/). In React 16 and Angular 4 breaking changes occur but I noticed that both projects made statements like that they ["will be backward compatible, though as with all major updates, there will be a few small breaking changes"](https://techcrunch.com/2017/04/18/facebook-announces-react-fiber-a-rewrite-of-its-react-framework/). I notice this with more than those two projects.

It seems strange to functionally say it is backwards compatible except for the parts that aren't backwards compatible. Why would a project choose to make such a redundant statement? This makes me wonder if there are plural definitions for backwards compatibility that I'm simply not aware of (and one that Semver does not acknowledge).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like they just mean "mostly backward compatible".

The definition of "backward compatible" pretty much is "not breaking stuff".  But if there are some small changes to rarely used things, that only affect a very small portion of users, it may still be accurate to describe a new version as backward compatible overall.

Answer (score 10):

There are a couple of things which make backwards compatibility non-trivial.

First, one constraint that is often used is that your code will compile without change in a backwards compatible change while in a non-backwards compatible change it may require code changes for your code to compile against the new version.  Of course, this constraint isn't useful for JavaScript.

This leads to the general idea, which is that the *public* "contract" of the code doesn't change.  Types are a formalization of an approximation of the public contract.  A test suite is another formalization of an approximation of the public contract.  That is, in a backwards compatible change, all tests in the old test suite should still pass.  Unfortunately, what's part of the public contract is almost never fully formally specified and is often not even fully specified by any means.   The public contract is what the library developers are committed to maintaining and the only thing you can rely upon as a consumer, but, especially in a language like JavaScript, there are myriads of details that are also visible which aren't part of the public contract and thus can't be relied upon. Of course, this doesn't stop people from relying on them.

Finally, there's the awkward case where a library doesn't meet its own public contract, i.e. it's buggy.  In this case, consumers obviously are forced to rely on the actual behavior of the library and not its intended behavior. Fixing the bug, bringing the library more in line with its public contract, will now break those consumers. Avoiding this is called maintaining [bug-compatibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bug_compatibility) and is a nightmare most developers want to avoid. I would say the "unspoken consensus" is that bugs can be fixed without notice.

Ultimately, it's hard to make any significant change to a code base (as opposed to a pure addition), especially in a language like JavaScript, that produces no programmatically observable difference. What serves as the (partial, informal) specification of the public contract usually leaves it unclear what behavior is guaranteed in various corner cases. Even given a complete specification, it is usually prohibitively expensive to actually verify that the code meets it. So at the end of the day, what constitutes "backwards compatible" is usually not sharply delineated, and even if it was (in a meaningful sense) it would probably be too expensive to actually verify.

So, yeah, the developers *hope* that the change is "backwards compatible", just like they hope that the code behaves as its nominally specified to do, but everyone has been around the block enough times to know that such hopes are unfounded.

Answer (score 2):

> will be backward compatible, though as with all major updates, there
>   will be a few small breaking changes

The statement is taken out of context and I guess you misunderstand it.

Originally there is:

> Alpert stressed that **React Fiber** will be backward compatible, though
>   as with all major **React** updates, there will be a few small breaking
>   changes.

React Fiber is an internal engine change. And ***exactly this change is backward compatible***. But still, **there are other changes** which are **not** backward compatible.

Answer (score 0):

For me if code is backwards compatible it means that, the developers have made all attempts (bugs are sometimes a Hazard) to make sure that moving from one version to the next will be easy and not require a change in your code.

However when they mention breaking changes, this means usually that the changes which you need to make should be documented and this documentation should be available to you, thus the changes that you need to make are known and can be explained.

Knowledge of breaking changes is much better than suck it and see.